# When can I run a remote async call when starting a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-asynctask

This is more of a design approach as I am new to Android.
I have a fragment that displays some data to the user.
The user presses a button and then I should display in another fragment a list of items. This list of items came after a request to a remote server.
Question: Where is the best place to put the call that does the remote request?
Run it before creating the activity that will display then and pass them somehow  to the activity/fragment that will display them or start the activity/fragment and do the remote call (via async task of course) on the onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the task and its relationship to the other components. Is this task closely related to the respective frag/activity? Then you could start the components, show a progression to the user and then the apropriate results.
Is it more loosely coupled, then you could implement a publish/subscribe message like mechanism, where the components subscribe to the task and the task publishes its result, when they're ready or the subscribers could even pull the data when necessary.

It's really up to you and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure exactly how can I combine the code. I mean I have the activity/fragment showing the data, and I can start the other activity/fragment but where/how exactly I populate the activity/fragment I start I am not clear

Answer (score 0):

If I look at the [Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating), i believe it is a good idea to start you async call in the `Fragment#onResume()` method.

All data you need for async call can be delivered via `Bundle`

Example:

MainActivity:

```
SearchResultFragment newFragment = new SearchResultFragment ();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("searchinput", input.getText()); // input from other fragment will be send to the MainActivity
newFragment.setArguments(args);

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Fragment:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    ...
    Bundle b = getAttributes();
    String searchInput = b.getString("searchinput"); 
    asyncSearch(searchInput);
}
```

Don't forget. Every time your fragment returns to the layout from the back stack, the method onResume() will be called. So perhaps you should to use some boolean flag:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    ...
    if(startSearchTask){
        Bundle b = getAttributes();
        String searchInput = b.getString("searchinput"); 
        asyncSearch(searchInput); // sets startSearchTast -> FALSE
    }
}
```

Comment: But  `onResume` is called after a pause only, so how will this work?

Comment: @Jim look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating